# SPA на React, как прокинуть пропс

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Задача заключается в том, чтобы пробросить ID элемента в новый React компонент

сылка на кодсанудбокс помогите разобраться

---

codesoundboxhttps://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cloud-5glcu

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параметры роутера для этого.

В `index.js` добавьте `:id` как параметр URL.

`<Route path='/info/:id' component={TvShowInfo} />`

На списке сл ссылками подставьте `id` фильма в параметр URL.

`` <Link to={`/info/${id}`}>{original_name}</Link> ``

А в компоненте 
`tvshowinfo.js`
можно вывести `id` из параметров роутера.

```js
    import React from "react";

    export const TvShowInfo = props => {
      console.log(props);
        return(
            <div>{ props.match.params.id }</div>
        )
    }
```